# How to set "resultDataContents" in Neo4jrb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I want to visualise data from Neo4j with the frontend-library D3.js in an Rails application, using Neo4jrb. For example I could use the following query to get my graph data.

```
query = "MATCH path = (a)-[b]->(c) RETURN path"
result = Neo4j::Session.current.query(query)
```

But this query is not giving me the exact data I want.

According to the [Neo4j data visualisation guide](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) there is a possibility to set the parameter `resultDataContents` to `"graph"`. (
[Neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/index.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format) for "resultDataContents")

This is exactly what I need for my application. Is there any possibility to set this parameter in Neo4jrb, or another idea how to achieve such a result?

Comment: Not sure of ruby but I have written some raw Cypher query to retrieve nodes and relationships from neo4j (an old version), hope it helps: https://github.com/paradite/Graphpedia/blob/master/models/term.js#L476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not currently.  The `neo4j-core` gem (which the `neo4j` gem uses) was build to abstract away the REST format.  The `"graph"` format returns data in a different way.

You have a couple of options.  You could make the JSON queries yourself or you could retrieve the nodes and relationships from the queries that you perform and then build your own nodes/relationships structure which is returned.  This might be more future-proof anyway if you ever want to switch to [Bolt](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-bolt-neo4js-upcoming-binary-protocol-p).

A way that you might do this in your case:

```
query = "MATCH path = (a)-[b]->(c) RETURN nodes(path) AS nodes, rels(path) AS rels"
result = Neo4j::Session.current.query(query)
response = {nodes: [], rels: []}
result.each do |row|
  response[:nodes].concat(row.nodes)
  response[:rels].concat(row.rels)
end
response[:nodes].uniq!
response[:rels].uniq!
```

Comment: thanks, but I have one further problem with your idea. `nodes` are identified by their `uuid`. Inside of `rels` the start- and end-node are identified by `neo-id`, so it's not possible to match them (to use in D3 for example) ?

Comment: You should be able to get the `neo_id` for nodes by calling the `neo_id` method

Comment: Thanks, I got a nice solution with your tips  :)